# "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:" for function in swift in tests

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have two targets in my Swift project:

1. app
2. tests

There is a function in app target that is not used anywhere in the app, but it is used in tests. As a result I get build error: `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:`. It says that the function is undefined and it is referenced from tests.

It looks like compiler removes this unused function from app.

**Question:** How to make unused function included in the app build?

Note: I do not want to add app's source file to `Compile Sources` of the test target. I prefer marking app's functions as `public` and then import the app module in tests instead.

### Current (imperfect) solution

Here is how I currently make it build functions which are unused in the app. This way I can use them in tests.

```
class IncludeUnusedHack {
  init() {
    if NSDate.date().timeIntervalSinceNow > 10_000_000 {
      MyClass.unusedFunctionOne()
      MyClass.unusedFunctionTwo()
    }
  }
}

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  let unusedHack = IncludeUnusedHack()
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in Xcode up through 6.1 Beta 2. It looks like Xcode 6.1 Beta 3 fixes it though (released today, 9/29). From the release notes:

> **Testing**
>
> • Dead code stripping no longer removes public declarations from Swift
>   application targets which are needed by unit testing. (18173029)

Comment: Confirmed. Problem is fixed in Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1042b)

Answer (score 2):

I faced such a problem too and then I solved by turning off an option.

`app(in TARGETS) > Build Settings > Linking > Dead Code Stripping`